# May I describe my character's Mobile feat as parkour or freerunning?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, feats, movement

Let's say in 5th ed D&D I take the Mobile feat, then use the Dash and Cunning Action. My PC's base speed is now +10, and I ignore difficult terrain, moving twice my new and improved base speed.

Using a halfling rogue as an example:

- Speed goes from 25 base, to 35 base
- Uses Dash as a bonus action, which gives a total of 70 that round
- **Ignores** difficult terrain.
- On top of that he can still make an attack against a creature (Mobile comes in handy here) provoking no opportunity attacks from that creature
- He continues to run past finishing his movement.

Can I call this Parkour/Freerunning as far as adding flavor and role-playing to the battlefield? It seems to fit.

Comment: Is your question whether people would describe this as parkour  (in which case this is very likely to be closed as primarily opinion-based) or whether you've understood the rules correctly and have  described them here correctly?

Comment: A little of both. I made the correlation a little while ago and I wanted the opinion of this community, but then when I was typing up the question, I realized that I might have misinterpreted it, so I thought I'd make the question useful as well and confirm my understand of the Mobile rules.

Comment: This site has a one question per post policy and doesn't handle opinion based questions very well. I suggest you edit this question to only ask about whether you've interpreted the rules correctly and not ask for opinions.

Comment: Mark already gave the perfect answer. . .  so I'm not that worried about it.

Comment: I think two things about this question.  1. It is indeed two different questions (check my calculation and can I describe this as parkour) which would be better split.  2. It's not really opinion-based, because the initial confusion is really whether you have discretion in describing things or not - I know as it's stated "can I describe this as parkour" is opinion-based, but he's really asking (and Mark has answered from the frame of) "am I allowed to pick descriptions of game stuff outside the RAW, for example:" with an answer of "yes, you are always welcome to re-skin game mechanics."

Comment: I shall edit to appease the moderator gods.

Comment: @Cadaran Already got it, no worries!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Sure.**

You can describe your Mobile halfling's movement however you want; something like parkour or freerunning is certainly an option. Just remember you don't get any other benefits beyond what is defined by the feat; the DM could reasonably call for Dexterity (Acrobatics) checks if you want to move in ways not allowed by Mobile.

Your breakdown of the possible move-attack-move combination for a rogue with Mobile is correct. The DM might well put you in circumstances where you can't always take advantage of this, but that's part of the fun.

Comment: I recently learned that "Slow" kills rogues... we fought a white dragon and won, and I didn't get a single attack off on it. . .  because I was slowed.  So yes, I'm familiar with DMs putting one in difficult situations.

Comment: @Cadaran that's odd. Even if slowed you should be able to land a couple ranged sneak attacks in most scenarios! May I ask what happened?

Comment: The lair blocked me, by the time I got magic weapon cast and could get around the ice wall that popped up in front of me, my teammates already had him fleeing with his tail between his legs.